# Oracle number to decimal

Tags: oracle, plsql

How I can select a number value in decimal, just like 12 to  12.00, without using to_char in oracle?

Comment: I don't want to use a lenghthy format. Can I use any cast to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL*Plus, you can format the output by changing the column format:

```
SQL> desc temp
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 FIELD1                                             VARCHAR2(100)
 FIELD2                                             VARCHAR2(100)

SQL> select * from temp;

        ID FIELD1     FIELD2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 hello      yyyy
         2 hello      yyyy

SQL> col id format 999.99
SQL> select * from temp;

     ID FIELD1     FIELD2
------- ---------- ----------
   1.00 hello      yyyy
   2.00 hello      yyyy
```

Answer (score 2):

You can  use

```
Select To_char(ID,'9990.99') from temp
```

0 is must for the formatting. If you want `0.00` value (eg:0.10,0.06) you have to put 0 inside the format without 0 it will look like this .00(eg:.10,.06). Check it out here

Without 0

```
Select To_char(0,'999.99') from Dual
```

With 0

```
Select To_char(0,'9990.99') from Dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to `NUMBER(9, 2)` (the 9 is arbitrary, use something else if you want) and it will be in that form.

However note that once you put it into your application, the representation is up to whatever language that uses.  If it represents that data type as a float, you'll get a float and it will no longer have the format you want.  In that case you are better off not formatting it until the number is outside of the database.

Comment: Hi, When I cast the number like ,select cast('5' AS number(9,2)) from dual; ,it is giving the output only '5' not 5.00.

Comment: @Remya: you're missing how number is stored with how it can be presented. If you need it to be presented as 5.00 - use to_char()